# How to assign IPV6 on Google Cloud VM instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Good day,
I am new to google cloud plateform please help.
How can i assgin ipv6 for my instance on google cloud, i have created an ipv6 but is says not in use just as in picture below.
[image]

Comment: Next time try to google a little more https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/configure-ipv6-address being new to something does not mean you cannot investigate on your own

Comment: @FerreginaPelona thank you, but I did visit all this first it didn’t make sense after following it, as I said I am new to google cloud, I wonder why someone on google made it that difficult just to assign an IP address to a vm, other provider like digital ocean click here and their and your are done. Anyways I will just get someone on Fiverr to do it for me. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documemtation shared by @Ferregina Pelona.

`You can configure IPv6 addresses on a virtual machine instance (VM) if the subnet that the VM is connected to has an IPv6 range configured.` First thing to do, make sure that there is a [IPv6](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-modify-vpc-networks#subnet-enable-ipv6) configured into your network.

Though, Google Cloud Platform allows users to connect to Global Load Balancer (this has external IP) using IPv6 but [VPC Network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc) DO NOT support IPv6.

Check out this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ipv6) on GCP's Global Load Balancer.

Comment: Thank you all, but we have switched to Linode and guess what it didn't take a sec to set ipv6.